# How to add Discord user profile banner in my discord.py bot

Tags: python, discord.py

I created an discord.py bot. Soon after I created it. To make it look decent I want to add discord user profile banner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily add a banner by going to your bot and then adding a picture to the banner.

[image: Discord Developer Banner pic]

I think it doesn't matter whether you have nitro or not

Answer (score 2):

Banners for bots aren't supported by Discord yet. It is only available to normal users with an active Nitro subscription.

Answer (score 0):

from now you can add banners in discord bot by simply going in the bot
section in discord devlopper portal